# How to update foreground service when app is closed?

Tags: java, android, notifications, foreground-service

I'm continuously updating notifications using the Foreground Service. However, after the user forcibly shuts down the app, the notification disappears, so the notification cannot be continuously updated. Even if the user shuts down the app, I want to update the notification while keeping the data intact before shutting down. How can you implement it?

> app code

```java
// start service
Intent intent = new Intent(getReactApplicationContext(), ForegroundService.class);
intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_FOREGROUND_SERVICE_START);
intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_CONFIG, Arguments.toBundle(notificationConfig));
getReactApplicationContext().startService(intent);
// update service
Bundle updateBundle = Arguments.toBundle(notificationConfig);
NotificationHelper mNotificationHelper = NotificationHelper.getInstance(this.reactContext);
Notification updateNotification = mNotificationHelper.buildNotification(this.reactContext, updateBundle);
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, updateNotification);
```

> Service code

```java
public class ForegroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null) {
            if (action.equals(Constants.ACTION_FOREGROUND_SERVICE_START)) {
                if (intent.getExtras() != null && intent.getExtras().containsKey(NOTIFICATION_CONFIG)) {
                    Bundle notificationConfig = intent.getExtras().getBundle(NOTIFICATION_CONFIG);
                    if (notificationConfig != null && notificationConfig.containsKey("id")) {
                        Notification notification = NotificationHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                                .buildNotification(getApplicationContext(), notificationConfig, NotificationType.FOREGROUND);
                        if(notificationConfig.getBoolean("ongoing")) {
                            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
                        }
                        startForeground((int)notificationConfig.getDouble("id"), notification);
                    }
                }
            } else if (action.equals(Constants.ACTION_FOREGROUND_SERVICE_STOP)) {
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }
}
```

> AndroidManifest

```xml
<service android:name="com.example.foregroundservice.ForegroundService" android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: Did you try `onTaskRemoved` callback ?

Comment: @StanislavBondar How to work?